# How do I install nginx when a dependant package is broken?

Tags: 14.04, nginx

Seems like a really simple question.

But, I'm trying to create a docker container containing nginx and it breaks.

My dockerfile contains...

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -yqq upgrade
RUN apt-get -f install
RUN apt-get -yq install --no-install-recommends nginx
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN sed -i '/access_log/s|/[^;]\+|/dev/stdout|' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN sed -i '/error_log/s|/[^;]\+|/dev/stdout|' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN chmod 777 /dev/stdout
```

But partway through I get:

```
After this operation, 916 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libfreetype6 amd64 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
2015/03/23 21:58:01 The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get -yq install libfreetype6] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I assume this is a bug.  I don't have time to file a bug report and just need this working really soon.

I'm not sure why nginx even depends on freetype.  Is there perhaps a way to install this without freetype and still have nginx work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple nginx packages available. The default, `nginx-core`, depends on some font-related packages which bring in `libfreetype6`. The smallest one,`nginx-light` doesn't depend on `libfreetype6`:

```
$ apt-rdepends nginx-light | grep freetype 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
$
```

So, for a quick fix, install `nginx-light`.